# Can an existing group be assigned as a subgroup?

Tags: gitlab

I created a project group in the past but now we have created a company level group.
Is it possible to assign the project group as subgroup under the company level group ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can transfer group by going to Group --> General --> Advanced

[image]